# KStream Join with GlobalKTable over non-key values

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to join KStream with GlobalKTable, the join is not completely on keys.

```
GlobalKTable<String, Employee> employeesDetails = builder.globalTable("EMPLOYEE_TOPIC",..);
KStream<String,String> empIdOverLoginUserId = builder.stream("LOG_TOPIC", ….);
```

I want to join empIdOverLoginUserId with employeesDetails over empIdOverLoginUserId's value over employeesDetails's key.

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second parameter of KStream-GlobalKTable join is a `KeyValueMapper` to map KStream record (key-value) to the key of GlobalKTable you want to join, you can use this to use empIdOverLoginUserId's value as key when joining with GlobalKTable:

```
empIdOverLoginUserId.join(
                employeesDetails, 
                (userKey, userValue) -> userValue, 
                (userValue, employeesDetailValue) -> employeesDetailValue)
```

Comment: Be aware of: If a `KStream` input record key or value is `null` the record will not be included in the join operation and thus no output record will be added to the resulting `KStream`. If `keyValueMapper` returns `null` implying no match exists, no output record will be added to the resulting `KStream`.